# How do I replace a double quote inside double quoted string using regular expressions?

Tags: regex

Currently i am getting following XML element:

```
<xylem ABC="""" />
```

I want to replace it as following:

```
<xylem />
```

Can anyone give me regexp pattern?

Comment: Your questions is about replacing double quotes. Why has the attribute ABC been removed too?

Comment: I want to remove attribute also

Comment: What language or tool are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ruby:

```
"<xylem ABC=\"\"\"\" />".gsub(/\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+=['"]([".]*)['"]/, "")
```

Using JavaScript:

```
"<xylem ABC=\"\"\"\" />".replace(new RegExp(/\s*[A-Za-z0-9]+=['"]([".]*)['"]/), "")
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>[RegExp Pattern](http://www.regexr.com/38uu5)</kbd>

#### Use this pattern

```
([A-Z])\w+="+("{1,})"/ig
```